# Running integration tests separately from unit tests in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

The convention for creating tests in django is to place tests in modules named `tests_*.py` and to run then as `python manage.py test`.

This will run all tests defined tests in all modules named tests.

The challenge I have come across is that integration tests may require significant setup of resources e.g. connection to external services. I would imagine mocking out those services in integration tests would cause integration tests to loose their meaning.

I am inquiring therefore of the best practice in running only unit tests and only run integration tests when unit tests are running properly.

The only way I can imagine is to place `integration tests` in files named with a different pattern such as `integration_*.py` and then use the pattern parameter when running integration tests as specified by the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/)

Like this `python manage.py test --pattern="integration_*"`.

In this way when `python manage.py test` is called integration tests will be ignored.

Does anyone have a suggestion or recommendation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Tagging test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#tagging-tests) to handle this. Try to tag your test by a name then:

```
./manage.py test --tag=integration
```